# Dropping rows on two dataframes based on index

Tags: pandas, dataframe, label

I am building this function:

```
def filna_intake(df):
    for j in ['bottom 25% bottom 25%', 'top 25% top 25%', 'mid 50% mid 50%', \
         'mid 50% top 25%', 'mid 50% bottom 25%', 'top 25% mid 50%', 'bottom 25% mid 50%', \
         'top 25% bottom 25%', 'bottom 25% top 25%']:
        df.drop(df.loc[df['intake'] == j].index, inplace=True)

return df
```

And it works fine if I call `filna_intake(predictors)`. But I want it to drop the corresponding row on another dataframe called `labels`. How can I do that inside this function? How can I get the index and tell my function to drop the corresponding row in `labels`?

Edit:

[image: Saple of the data]

Comment: Please update a sample of your both dataframes.

Comment: There it is :))

Comment: Please correct me, if I am wrong. you are looking for `How can I get the index and tell my function to drop the corresponding row in labels?` that's it?

Comment: yes, that is right! I drop the row in `predictors` but I need to drop the corresponding row in `labels`. I know the labels and I can drop them just right, but it is more elegant to build this function and I want to learn how to do it.